# Scapegoat theory and PA

Tags: logic, incompleteness

A theory T is scapegoat if for every formula A with only one free variable there exist a closed term s such that T proves:
(∃x(¬A(x)))⇒¬A(s)
I think it is an expectable property for each theory since it says that if there is a x which A(x) does not hold for it the we can substitute a closed term instead of x . And we can expect for an aribtrary theory this statement can be proved in that theory. Please explain intuitively if I am wrong and what is my mistake.
My second question is showing that PA is not scapegoat theory. I read "Scapegoat theory!" question but I cant understand it and its relation to Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every theory is Scapegoat, its actually very unreasonable. Take PA, there is 
the Godel sentence $G$
now 
$$G\equiv \neg \exists n (n \text{is a proof  of} G)$$

We cannot prove $G$ in PA. If PA were a scapegoat theory there would be some fixed number $k$, say such that 
$$PA \vdash \exists n (n \text{is a proof  of} G) \rightarrow (k \text{is a proof  of} G)$$
or briefly, 
$$PA \vdash\neg G \rightarrow (k \text{is a proof  of} G)$$
Now we can check to see if $k$ is a proof of $G$, it wont be cause we cant prove it. So we have 
$$PA \vdash\neg G \rightarrow \text{a falsehood}$$

therefore,
$PA\vdash G$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Ok. Hence you say that because of Godel's incomleteness theorem, we have theories which are not scapegoat theory; that is if we have not Godel's incompleteness theorem, then every theory is scapegoat theory. Am I true?

Comment: @aminliverpool - I do not thin so. See Elliott Mendelson, *Introduction to mathematical logic* (4ed - 1997), page 87 for he definition of *scapegoat theory* and page 94 : **Ex.2.63(c)** : "prove that no predicate calculus is a scapegoat theory".

Comment: Well if there are no constants in the language, as is often the case, then you cannot be scapegoat.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA- Ok. I saw it. But what is intuitively mean? I think scapegoat property is expectable in each theory, but what does happen that we cant see this property in any predicate calculus, intuitively?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus- Mauro is right. Mendelson in his book said no predicate calculus is a scapegoat theory, and it is possible for predicate calculus to have countable individual constants.

Answer (score 0):

Theories with "built-in Skolem functions" have a stronger property: for any formula $\phi(v,w_1,\ldots,w_m)$ (together with the partition of variables), there is a function symbol $f$ such that
$$T\vDash \forall v,w_1,\ldots,w_m [\phi(v,w_1,\ldots,w_m)\rightarrow \phi(f(w_1,\ldots,w_m),w_1,\ldots,w_m)]$$

It's easy to show that for any theory $T$ in a language $\mathcal{L}$, there is a *Skolemization*: a theory $T^*$ in a language $\mathcal{L}^*$ such that $T^*$ has built in Skolem functions and is conservative over $T$ (if $T^*\vDash\phi$ and $\phi$ is a formula in $\mathcal{L}$ then $T\vDash\phi$).

In that sense, scapegoat (and stronger) theories are common, and any sufficiently expressive language is one.  In particular, the obstacle to PA having these properties isn't really related to Godel's theorem; it's because the underlying language has very terms.