# Predicate calculus is not scapegoat theory ?!

Tags: logic

A theory $T$ is a scapegoat theory if for every formula $A$ with only one free variable there exist a closed term s such that $T$ proves: $(\exists x(\neg A(x)))\Rightarrow \neg A(s)$

Why is any predicate calculus not a scapegoat theory?

Please prove it.

I think this property is expected for any theory, since it says that we can subsitute a term to a free variable. So why can’t we see this property in any predicate calculus?
By completeness theorem we know theorems are exactly logically valid.

Do you think "not scapegoateness property" is logically valid?

Comment: Well, for one, it was never accused of the JFK assassination. That's one of the hallmarks of being a scapegoat.

Comment: @Asaf: I think that this is an exercise in Mendelson's logic book, if I understand correctly. Of course "scapegoat" is not in any way standard terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823048/scapegoat-theory-and-pa) I've pointed at the following exercise in Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0412808307) (4ed - 1997), page 94 : **Ex.2.63(c)** : "prove that no predicate calculus is a scapegoat theory".

For the definition of *predicate calculus* see page 70 : for a language which contains denumerable many individual variables, individual constants (possibly none), function letters (possibly none) and predicate letters :

> a theory without *non-logical* (or *proper*) axioms.

Thus, a *predicate calculus* is a "degenerate" firts-order theory in any signature which has **no** proper axioms.

Following Mendelson's definition of *scapegoat theory* [page 84], for a predicate calculus  we have that :

> for any formula $\mathcal B$ with only one free variable $x$, there is a *closed term* $t$ such that :
>
> (A) --- $\vdash \exists x \lnot \mathcal B(x) \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot B(t)$.

The formula above is equivalent to :

> (B) --- $\vdash \mathcal B(t)\rightarrow \forall x \mathcal B(x)$.

But this formula is **not** *valid*.

Consider the language with constant $c$ and unary predicate letter $P$.

Consider the following instance of (B) :

> $P(c) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$;

we can find interpretations which falsify it : choose a domain with more than one object and assign to $P$ a non-empty *proper* subset of the domain.

Thus, if (B) is **not** valid, neither (A) is. By soundness, (A) is not *provable*.

Comment: I downvoted the original (and was leaving a comment when you deleted it). It looked like a mistake with quantifiers. The defn. of a scapegoat theory is "for each $B$ there is a term $s$ such that $T \vdash (\exists x)B(x) \to B(s)$". It seemed you read it as "for each $B$ and all terms $s$, $T \vdash (\exists x)B(x) \to B(s)$". At least, the latter is is needed in general to assert that your formula (B) is not valid.  However, now that you state Mendelson's idiosyncratic definition, the argument is OK in this case, because constants are indistinguishable when there are no nonlogical axioms.

Comment: In other words, with no nonlogical axioms, if $T$ proves $(\exists x)B(x) \to B(s)$ then it also proves $(\exists x)B(x) \to B(s')$ for every constant $s'$. So the two quoted phrases in my previous comment are equivalent in this specific situation.

Comment: I mean his definition of "a" predicate calculus as a first-order theory in any signature that has no nonlogical axioms.

Comment: @CarlMummert - Ok. You and Mauro proved that a predicate calculus with only one constant, this assertion is true. But how canwe prove in general for any predicate calculus containing any number of constants, no predicate calculus is a scapegoat theory ?

Comment: @aminliverpool - assuming that my revised answer, as reviewed by Carl, is correct, we have proved thet a formula $\exists x \lnot B(x) \rightarrow \lnot B(t)$ is **not** valid. Thus - by *soundness* - is not provable without proper (i.e.non-logical) axioms.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - Ok. You proved the formula in not valid for special predicate calculus. How can you prove this assertion for general predicate calculus ?

Comment: @aminliverpool - what is the difference between two *predicate calculuses* ? Only the signatures, i.e. the different non-logical symbols : predicate and constants. Because they have **no** proper axioms, they have all the same axioms : the *logical* ones. Thus, a fomula of the "form"  ∃x¬B(x)→¬B(t) is **not** provable in **any** pc, independently of the specific constant $t$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA- Ok. I agree with you. But you proved the non-validity of the formula for a theory whose language has only one individual constant. However general predicate calculus has many individual constants.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA- Ok. I made a big mistake. Excuse me for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

Here are three examples. I wrote this out at length because I want to be able to link to it for future questions about the "scapegoat property".

#### Not every theory is a scapegoat theory

First, here is an example showing that general theories are not scapegoat theories. Consider a theory in the language of pure equality. The only relation symbol is "$=$", and there are no constant symbols or function symbols. This theory proves $(\exists x)[x = x]$. But there are no closed terms at all, so the theory cannot be a scapegoat theory.

#### Every theory can be extended to a scapegoat theory in a larger language

Now here is an example of how to make any theory into a scapegoat theory. Given a theory $T$, for each formula $A(x)$ with one free variable we add a new constant symbol $c_A$ and a new axiom
$$
(\exists x) A(x) \to A(c_A)
$$
This may cause new formulas with one free variable to appear, so we repeat the process of adding new constants until we obtain a theory in which every formula $A(x)$ with one free variable has an associated constant $c_A$. This new theory will have the scapegoat property, and will be conservative over the original theory: if a formula in the language of the original theory is provable in the extended theory, that formula is also provable in the original theory.

This is a special case of a more general process called Skolemization.

#### Peano arithmetic does not have the scapegoat property

This example will be a more nontrivial theory without the scapegoat property. For this example, some familiarity with the incompleteness theorems is needed.

Let $T$ be first-order Peano arithmetic, PA. Unlike in the first example, PA has many closed terms, such as $1+1+1$. In particular it has a term for every natural number.

Let $A(x)$ be the statement "$x$ codes a proof of $0=1$ from the axioms of first-order Peano arithmetic". The key points of the incompleteness theorem are:

- $A(x)$ is expressible as a formula of PA with only bounded quantifiers
- $(\exists x)A(x)$ is consistent with PA, but not provable or disprovable

Assume for a contradiction that PA has the scapegoat property. Pick a nonstandard model of PA in which $(\exists x)A(x)$ holds. According to the scapegoat property, we can choose a term $s$ such that PA proves $(\exists x)A(x) \to A(s)$.   Thus $A(s)$ holds in our nonstandard model.

Because $A(x)$ has only bounded quantifiers, if $A(s)$ holds in any model of PA then it holds in every model of PA. But this means $A(s)$ must be provable from PA, so $(\exists x)A(x)$ is also provable. This contradicts the second bullet above. Thus PA does not have the scapegoat property for the formula $A(x)$.

Comment: Thnk you for your attention. As I mentioned in my question, in fist order theory any predicate calculus is not scapegoat theory. Why this is true? A predicate calculus can has infinite individual constants. My second point is that, is it true to say that because of only second incompleteness theorem PA is not a scapegoat theory ?

Comment: The question "any predicate calculus is not a scapegoat theory" is not clear to me. Can you give a reference to what you are asking about, or edit the question to be very specific about it?

Comment: My reference is mathematical logic Mendelson. And he said in his book this assertion

Comment: @aminliverpool: I gave an example that *is* a scapegoat theory, which is why it seems hard for me to explain why "any predicate calculus is not a scapegoat theory". Can you give a specific definition (in your question) of exactly what theory you are calling "predicate calculus"? Thanks,

Comment: Language of predicate calculus can contain infinite variables, individual constants, function letters and predicate letters. The theory has two more logical axioms in addition to propositional calculus. And its inference rules are modus ponens and generalization.

Comment: @user87128: I just saw this post and would like to know if you have solved this problem (although this is posted a long long time ago).